# I have registered a john.doe@gmail.com account, is doe.john@gmail.com automatically reserved?

Tags: gmail, account-management

I'm an old Gmail user from 2004 and I've always been curious about it.

Registering `john.doe@gmail.com` as a new Gmail account, is `doe.john@gmail` automatically reserved?

If I try to send a mail to `doe.john@gmail`, the mail does not arrive to me and I don't get any *Mail Delivery Subsystem* warning so it seems the address is alive in some way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you registered the account `john.doe@gmail.com` then you aren't going to get emails addressed to `doe.john@gmail.com` as that would be a totally different account.

I tested this with my own Gmail account and I get bounce back saying the account doesn't exist.  You probably didn't get a bounce back because the account (`doe.john@gmail.com`) *does* exist - it must have been registered by someone else.

Comment: that's strange though; in 7 years I have never received a mail sent by any friend/parents/whatever of `doe.john@gmail.com` using `john.doe@gmail.com` as address. I mean, it's pretty easy to make a mistake and invert name and surname; I did it many times.

Comment: @systempuntoout  dont forget that the . is an optional in the email and can be placed anywhere so it would result in the taking up of a lot of variation per registered email

Comment: it is optional, but the most classic place is between name and surname or viceversa.

Comment: By giving your email as `john.doe@gmail.com`. The most common mistake would be miss out or to misplace the `.` Swapping around the first and last name wouldn't be a common mistake, IMO.

Comment: @Barry uhm, probably I see it as a common mistake because, unluckily, my mail at work is `doe.john@work.com` . So, sometimes a friend swaps name and surname by mistake OR I directly give him/her swapped :P

Comment: You can however use any amount of `.` in your email address and still get the emails if the person who sent it forgot one or more `.`s.